# Want example code for reading the VSS snapshot journal

Tags: c++, windows, windows-server-2008, volume-shadow-service

Is there a way to read the VSS snapshot area directly on Windows?
Assume that you have created a VSS snapshot; and want to read the snapshot to figure out:
- which block was copied (the block reference to its origin)
- the copied data (cow / saved changes)

If someone knows how to know how the structure for pwszDiffAreaVolumeName looks like on disk?

Regards Tomas